# Adding a view contained in a folder to my ContentView causes an error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have added a view (that I have moved to a `Components` folder) to my `ContentView` but this causes an `Use of unresolved identifier 'QuotaNode'`.

Here is `ContentView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct QuotasView: View {
  var body: some View {
    // NavigationView to be removed once we can
    NavigationView {
      List {
        Section(header: Text("ASKIAFACE DEMO")) {
          NavigationLink(
            destination: QuotaDetails()) {
            QuotaNode()
          }
          NavigationLink(
            destination: QuotaDetails()) {
            QuotaNode()
          }
          NavigationLink(
            destination: QuotaDetails()) {
            QuotaNode()
          }
          NavigationLink(
            destination: QuotaDetails()) {
            QuotaNode()
          }
        }
      }
      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Quotas"), displayMode: .inline)
      .foregroundColor(.bodyTextPrimary)
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
  }
}
```

Now, here's my project structure:

Project

- ContentView.swift
- DummyView.swift
- Components (folder)

  - QuotaNode.swift

The above code was working fine until I moved `QuotaNode.swift` to that `Components` folder. I could easily revert that but I'd prefer to be able to maintain a cleaner project structure (with folders for extensions, helpers, ...). Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What about - clean & rebuild?

Comment: @Asperi ogm, was just the IDE throwing a random error apparently. A `Clean Build Folder` + Build did the trick apparently. Many thanks for your help!